# Decimal pad UITextfield and keyboard extensions on iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm using a `UITextField` with its input type set to Decimal Pad. If the latest keyboard that had been used was the Bitmoji keyboard and the user taps on the the text-field then the Bitmoji keyboard appears and it doesn't allow the user to change it back to the decimal pad (from the small globe icon on the bottom left of the keyboard).

If the user taps on another text-field with the default keyboard type, he can change the keyboard from Bitmoji to the default, and then if he taps on the decimal text-field the decimal pad appears.

So the problem occurs when the user taps on the decimal text-field and the last used keyboard was the Bitmoji keyboard.

If it provides any help, the text-field has been set up as an outlet from a storyboard.

Has anyone experienced something relevant (with Bitmoji or any other keyboard extension)? Is this an iOS bug?

Update:

This happens with other keyboard extensions as well. The only way that I have fixed this for now is to disable all keyboard extensions from my app.

Comment: Tried with a new project with both NumberPad & DecimalPad for keyboard type. Didnt observe this issue, (Xcode 9.3, iOS 11.3)

Comment: I tried it on a new project as well (Xcode 9.3 & iOS 11.3) and it still happens. Have you tried it with two textfields (default & decimal pad) and having selected the Bitmoji keyboard on the first one and then tapping on the second one? Another thing to note is that I just tried with another keyboard extension and it has the same problem, so it isn't limited on the Bitmoji keyboard.

Comment: Yes I did try with two text fields.